# Has the phrase "such as" been used correctly in the sentence "You can make an offer with a phrase such as ..."?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I usually tend to struggle with the placement of the phrase "such as" in my sentences (I struggle to identify the appropriate times it could be used in a sentence). I was wondering if there is a grammatical rule for it that could help me find the proper placement of this phrase in a sentence.

(I'm always looking to improve on my English; so, I'd greatly appreciate it if you would point out any grammatical mistakes I've made in describing my question)

Comment: Concerning grammatical mistakes in asking your question: "I usually tend" is redundant. Essentially, to tend to do something means you usually do it. You can say "I usually struggle..." or "I tend to struggle..."

Answer (score 1):

"Such as" is used to precede an example of the thing preceding it. Your example sentence lacks sufficient context to determine whether it is being used correctly, but here's an example where it is correct:

> You can make an offer with a phrase such as "I'd like to make an offer".

Generally, the sentence structure "X such as Y" is correct if Y is an example of X.